# entering any password still logs in

Tags: php, mysql

I am **entering** any password but I am getting successful logins. I am confused.

php code:

```
// LOGIN USER
    // variable declaration
        $email = "";
        $mobile = "";
        $under_userid    = "";
        $errors = array(); 
        $_SESSION['success'] = "";
        require('php-includes/connect.php');


    session_start();

        if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

            if (empty($email)) {
                array_push($errors, "Email is required");
            }
            if (empty($password)) {
                array_push($errors, "Password is required");
            }

            if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $Hpassword = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$Hpassword'";
                $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                $_SESSION['userid'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
        $_SESSION['login_type'] = "user";
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
            }


        }
```

please help me

Comment: You never check the result of your query.

Comment: You just checked `count($errors) == 0`, executed a query, and irrespective of the result, `echo`ed Login Success

Comment: Several problems here.  Most serious: WHERE ARE YOU CHECKING THE RESULT OF YOUR QUERY??? Also: 1) Never "select *" unless you want all the fields.  2) Always try to use a prepared statement instead of "raw SQL".

Comment: Also, remember [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: ***Never*** have authorisation information travel the net as plain text: `$_POST['password']` raises a red flag with me.

Comment: `interning` has a special [meaning with java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()): please check the title of your question.

Comment: there are two ways of storing credentials in php: 1) `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` 2) the wrong way, that gets your database hacked, your data leaked and you sued in the long run

Answer (score 1):

You are getting login successful because there is no script which can track that provided password is in-correct or correct. So you need to add following if-statement for checking it,

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($mysqli_query) > 0){
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
        $_SESSION['login_type'] = "user";
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
    }
```

`mysqli_num_rows()` will get the rows of match data from database and if there is row the `if-statement` will be true and then you will only get successful login. Other wise it will be fail and you can show error to user.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checked here if username and password are correct or not.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $Hpassword = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$Hpassword'";
    $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $_SESSION['userid'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
    $_SESSION['login_type'] = "user";
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
}
```

Please correct it using if condition is there any field match with that username or password as below

```
if(count($mysqli_query)>0)
{
     echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
}
```